# iOS: Without GPS, is it possible to detect if user is driving a vehicle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

I am developing an App that has a popup message if the user is driving a vehicle. I've implemented SOMotionDetector library. This library works great, however I don't want to track the user's location and I definitely don't want to display a message asking permission to track their location. Is there another alternative?

Here is the coded I've added, not sure if it will help.

```
[SOLocationManager sharedInstance].allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = NO;

[[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance] startDetection];

[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].useM7IfAvailable = YES; //Use M7 chip if available, otherwise

[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].motionTypeChangedBlock = ^(SOMotionType motionType) {
    switch (motionType) {
        case MotionTypeNotMoving:
            break;
        case MotionTypeWalking:
            break;
        case MotionTypeRunning:
            break;
        case MotionTypeAutomotive:[self alertMessage];
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: I believe that the `automotive` motion type relies upon GPS in order to determine high-speed movement but you don't need to request location permissions as you aren't accessing the user's location;  This is if you use in the CoreMotion framework directly.  I have no idea what `SOMotionDetector` does.  However, CoreMotion doesn't have background notification, so if you want your app to receive motion updates in the background you will need to leverage one of the supported background modes, of which location updates is one

Comment: Hello @Weakman10122 , I am also searching for way to detect if user is driving a vehicle. Can you please share how you implemented this. Thanks looking forward for your response.

Comment: @ChanWarde Use this library https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMotionDetector. It worked well last time I used it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

1. You can use  Core Motion on devices to get an indication of whether
   the user  might be driving. **CoreMotion APIs** give you iOS' best
   guess as to the user's activity, but there's no guarantee it's 100%
   accurate. (For example, I'm not sure if riding a train might count
   as automotive. Also note that the different activity types are not
   mutually exclusive.) It's better for your app to check for the
   activity types you're interested in than to try to exclude the ones
   you don't want.
2. Check the user's current speed in the following method. If the user
   is traveling faster than 20-ish MPH, then I could assume that the
   user is in a car:

   ```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
      CLLocation *recentLocation = [locations lastObject];
      recentLocation.speed; //If speed is over 20 MPH, assume the user is not on their feet.
     }
   ```

Comment: Link to the relevant Core Motion API on Apple's site: [CMMotionActivity Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivity_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CMMotionActivityConfidence)

Comment: is it possible to fetch this in the background or if my app is killed?